# How to add additional variables to love plot?

Tags: r

I am using the **cobalt** package to make a love plot to illustrate covariate balance amongst variables. My code so far is:

```
W <- weightit(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3,
                    data = d1, 
                    method = "cbps",
                    over = FALSE)

love.plot(W, stats = c("c"), thresholds = c(cor = .1), 
          abs = TRUE, wrap = 20,
          var.order = "unadjusted", line = TRUE)
```

I want to show covariate balance of all my confounder variables (X1, X2, X3) that are used in the propensity score model as well as a few other variables (Z1, Z2, Z3) that are not confounders and thus not in the propensity score model. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Use the `addl` argument.